# Retrieving data from firebase to table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I am trying to create a to do list using firebase . My problem is when I am trying to retrieve data from the firebase to my table

```
//function to add to firebase 

func add (title : String , desc : String){

    myDic = ["title": "\(title)" , "desc": "\(desc)"]
    firebase_ref.childByAppendingPath("AllTasks").childByAppendingPath("\(count() + 1)").setValue(myDic)
    firebase_ref.childByAppendingPath("number").setValue("\(count() + 1)")
    task_count++


}

// my cell definition
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")


    let read = firebase_ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(snapshot.value.objectForKey("title"))
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(snapshot.value.objectForKey("desc"))

    })


        return cell
    }
```

as the result of this I get nils on my table as many as objects that I have in my firebase

Comment: You are using different paths for adding data and getting it back

Comment: Also, use [childByAutoId()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/#firebase_childByAutoId) instead of sequential numeric ids, which are [nothing but trouble](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase) in distributed systems.